# Passing arguments to Powershell Start-Job

Tags: powershell, process, background

I'm looking to start a tortoiseSVN update as a background process but I'm having no luck

```
Start-Job tortoiseproc -ArgumentList "/command:update /path:C:\MyDir /closeonend:2;"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have tortoiseSVN installed but it looks like you're missing the main scriptbloc of the job. Does this work?

```
 Start-Job { tortoiseproc $args} -ArgumentList "/command:update /path:C:\MyDir /closeonend:2"
```

Comment: That was it alright, thanks. Is there any way to report when the process has completed? Something like $job = Start-Job { tortoiseproc $args} -ArgumentList "/command:update /path:C:\MyDir /closeonend:2"; return $job.State - but that does not wait for the process to end so $job.State will always say "Running"

Comment: You can wait for it to finish, just pipe it to Wait-Job

Comment: Sorry I'm new to PS and I need to be handheld a bit. I'm looking to wait on the job but also clean up after returning the state of the job. So far it's not working, I'm mising some basic concepts I think Start-Job { tortoiseproc $args} -ArgumentList "/command:update /path:C:\MyDir /closeonend:2" | Wait-Job | Get-Job {$_.Id} | Remove-Job return {$_.State}

Comment: Wait for the job to finish and get its result: $j = Start-Job ... | Wait-Job | Recieve-Job